# Failed to Boot: Starting Version 219

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Got this when booting my computer:

```
PCC probe failed.
starting version 219
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
root@username:~#
```

Currently, I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04; dual boot with Windows 7. So can somebody help me to fix this? Thanks

UPDATE:
I tried to fix it with Boot Repair, it didn't work. For those who want to see the BootInfo summary can find it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11681073/